# Need help, if none of the checkboxes are checked do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, postdata

On my website, the "Sort By Category" works OK when your checking the checkboxes it appends each of each category and hides the rest of the other one.

What I want to do is be able to show all if category items if none of the checkboxes are check, if you go on the site and click on 2 categorys and uncheck them you will notice it will be empty.

The CSS item for the posts is the class = "rp-item".

This is what my category sort looks like right now,

```
function categorySort() {      
  $('#CategorySort').attr('firstclick', true);

  $('.cat-sort-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.cat-sort-bar').toggle(500);
  });

  $('.cat-sort-check').change(function() {
    if ( $('#CategorySort').attr('firstclick') == 'true') {
      $('.rp-item').css('display', 'none');
      $('#CategorySort').attr('firstclick', false);
    }

    $objectString = '.' + $(this).attr('showclass');

    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      $($objectString).show(500);
    } else {
      $($objectString).hide(500);
    }
  });
}

/* the code below was the one i tried to fix the issue,
what it did is it kinda worked but everytime i click the
2nd time on any of the check boxes or just switch
checkboxes it brings everything back instead of only
the posts from the checkbox. Thanks! */ 

else{
  $('.rp-item').css('display', 'inline-block');
  $('#CategorySort').attr('firstclick', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if none of checkbox checked by

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length < 1){
   alert('No one checked');
}
```

> Note : This code is just a basic .. check for classes and Ids yourself
>   and update this code in the event you want

Comment: Hey Man , Thanks 

Unfortunetely it did not work when i click on it it doesnt load up its posts and if i uncheck it shows nothing.

I just want it to show all rp-items if all of them are unchecked , and if i check one to continue to sort.

Right now it sorts but when none is checked it just shows nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$("input[type='checkbox' class='rp-item']:checked")` gives you a list of the checkboxes that are checked. You can then strap it inside an `if`:

```
if($("input[type='checkbox' class='rp-item']:checked").length > 0){
    // Do Something
}
```

And write your application logic inside of it.

"jQuery-less" approach:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("rp-item");
var nothingChecked = true;
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked == false)
        continue;
    else
        nothingChecked = false;
}
if(nothingChecked == true) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Hey Man , Thanks 

Unfortunetely it did not work when i click on it it doesnt load up its posts and if i uncheck it shows nothing.

I just want it to show all rp-items if all of them are unchecked , and if i check one to continue to sort.

Right now it sorts but when none is checked it just shows nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Hey check the else statement that i tried but it dint work any suggestions?